# Karate Robot Feature "Could not load Loader: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnijavacpp in java.library.path"

Tags: karate

I am trying to run the below feature using karate Robot. However it is opening browser and printing "Window found" but I am facing the error in second photo. Any help will be highly appreciated. I have already added a image 'choose-file.png' in my folder structure.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no one else has reported this so you have to help us replicate this. Maybe the combination of the OS, JRE version and Karate has issues.

Try to get this working on another machine and follow the instructions precisely as documented here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Karate-Robot-Windows-Install-Guide

Please consider contributing code as this is an open-source project: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide

Comment: Thanks for you reply @Peter Thomas, I am using different IDE than you mentioned in provided link. I am using codeReady. When I ran the same feature in Visual code it worked fine.